# What is the Difference between Microsoft dynamics CRM 2013 and Microsoft dynamics CRM online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Can anyone please help me understand the difference.
Is it that dynamics CRM 2013 is on-Premise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Version's of MS Dynamics CRM Online and On-Premise.
CRM Online is hosted by Microsoft.

See also [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online vs On-Premise](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2014/03/microsoft-dynamics-crm-online-vs-on-premise-what-option-is-best-suited-for-you/)